# React Navigation Tab load api on tab clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have tab navigator which loads all tab components. In every components all api calls which makes my app slow.

what i want is to load page and api only after I pressed the corresponding tab.

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make it lazy, from [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab):

> lazy - Whether to lazily render tabs as needed as opposed to rendering
>   them upfront.

Example:

```js
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Another: {
    screen: AnotherScreen,
  },
}, {
    lazy: true
});
```